How do people print text on GUI on Win3.1/95/98/... before Win2000?
I was checking online MSDN documentation, and was surprised to find that the TextOut and DrawText functions are supported since Windows 2000:

TextOutA function (wingdi.h)
DrawText function (winuser.h)
DrawTextExA function (winuser.h)

I once thought these two functions are as old as Windows GUI,
but it turns out not.
My puzzle is: since TextOut and DrawText are
unavailable before Windows 2000, how did people draw
text then? One of my guess is using the STATIC control,
but I am not sure.

You're misunderstanding what that line in the documentation means -- It's actually not making any statement about Windows versions prior to Win2000.  Lack of a statement that older versions have the function should not be construed as a statement that the function was absent from those versions.

@BenVoigt Yes, I thought that 'minimum supported version' means 'we don't have this before', but it turns out that it actually means something like 'we don't gurantee what's going on before, it might not be found, might be found but different, and might be just as good as the present systems, just that our company do not gurantee anything.'

Yes, and one practical effect is that they trimmed the documentation to not talk about differences between Win2000 and anything earlier.  It's quite likely that one or more of the flags were brand new in Win2000.

I think it is just because that the modern Windows API documentations only list availability starting with Windows 2000. Those functions are actually available in Windows 95/NT 4.0 SDK, declared at MSTOOLS\INCLUDE\WINGDI.H:2964, MSTOOLS\INCLUDE\WINUSER.H:4918, MSTOOLS\INCLUDE\WINUSER.H:4947.

DrawText() is not actually available there, but DrawTextA() and DrawTextW() are.
The ANSI variant of TextOut() and DrawText() are also available in Windows 3.1 SDK, but in a different header, WINDOWS.H, and has no A name suffix. DrawTextEx() doesn't seem to be there.

They are also available in Windows 1.01 SDK, albeit with a slightly different signature. Can't really be earlier than that.


Backward source-code compatibility: DrawTextA() and DrawTextW() are the actual function export names in the WinNT family, where DrawText is a C macro that resolves to one or the other depending on whether you have asked for “Unicode” or “ANSI” compilation. The original function back since Windows 1 (up to Windows Me) was called just DrawText(). This was all designed to minimize the effort to update existing programs for WinNT “Unicode”, and to help people maintain a single source code base that could compile to both Windows 95 (ANSI) or Windows NT (Unicode) with minimal changes.

@EuroMicelli DrawText is the Win16 name of the function and DrawTextA/DrawTextW are the Win32 names, regardless of OS. Win32s/Win95/98/ME supported only the A-suffixed versions of most functions, but they did use the A suffix.

@benrg I thought the W-suffixed functions were supported by Win32s/Win95/98/ME so you could start using Unicode right away?  That was a long time ago though, maybe my memory is faulty.

@MarkRansom Unicode was never supported natively by the Windows 9x family. Microsoft Layer for Unicode came much later on as a redistributable library, and even then it was incomplete.

IIRC most of the "W" functions weren't available on 9x without the "layer for unicode", but there were some exceptions and with care it was possible to build Unicode-supporting applications for 9x even without the layer for Unicode. IIRC office 2000 was unicode based.
